# Python - BeautifulSoup find strong and the next value of td class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following sample HTML table from a html page.

```html
<table id="fullRecordTable" valign="bottom" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="yellow" width="100%" summary="Vollanzeige des Suchergebnises">

...

  <tr>
    <td width="25%" class='yellow'>
      <strong>Sachbegriff</strong>
    </td>
    <td class='yellow'>
      Messung
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" class='yellow'>
      <strong>DDC-Notation</strong>
    </td>
    <td class='yellow'>
      530.8<br/>T1--0287<br/>542.3
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I am trying to print `"DDC-Notation"` and than the next three values: `"530.8"`, `"T1--0287"`, `"542.3"`

My code is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

talbes = soup.findAll('table', id='fullRecordTable').find_all('tr')

for table in talbes:
    tds = table.find_all('strong')  
    print tds.text
```

But it's doesn't work for the first.

P.S. Sorry, this is my first post. If I couldn't explain my problem, I'll try one more time

Comment: Hint: Check the Beautiful Soup documentation to learn about functions to get siblings (find_next_sibling etc.)

Comment: I tried this: 
`trs = soup.find('table', id='fullRecordTable').find_all('td')
for tr in trs:
 for t in tr:
  for row in t:    
   if 'DDC-Notation' in row:
    print "DDC", row`
This returns 'DDC-Notation'. How can I get the next td value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life is much easier if you use an interactive environment to debug your code because you can poke around looking for what you need.

In this case, I knew that you wanted to find a certain string. I looked for that in a direct way.

Having found it, I sought its grandparent, the `td` element and then the sibling of that `td`, another `td`.

I made a that into a variable called `td`, just for convenience because I wasn't sure how I would dig out the pieces you want.

Eventually I found that the `children` property contains a list that includes the items you need. It's merely a matter of stripping out HTML tags, and new-lines and blanks.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> strong = soup.find_all(string='DDC-Notation')
>>> strong
['DDC-Notation']
>>> strong[0].findParent()
<strong>DDC-Notation</strong>
>>> strong[0].findParent().findParent()
<td class="yellow" width="25%">
<strong>DDC-Notation</strong>
</td>
>>> strong[0].findParent().findParent().findNextSibling()
<td class="yellow">
      530.8<br/>T1--0287<br/>542.3
    </td>
>>> td = strong[0].findParent().findParent().findNextSibling()
>>> td
<td class="yellow">
      530.8<br/>T1--0287<br/>542.3
    </td>
>>> td.children
<list_iterator object at 0x00000000035993C8>
>>> list(td.children)
['\n      530.8', <br/>, 'T1--0287', <br/>, '542.3\n    ']
```

**Edit**: It occurred to me this morning that this answer might be more useful to you if I offered a consolidated script. In writing it I discovered (once again) that there's a little bit more to processing the items in a list like that than might appear to be the case.

When Python outputs most things it converts them to strings for us automatically. But, when you process the items in a list of HTML elements they will *elements* not strings and if you want to process them as strings then you must try to convert them first, hence the need for the line `item = str(item).strip()'. It converts elements to strings and discards whitespace.

```
import bs4
HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
strong = soup.find_all(string='DDC-Notation')
td = strong[0].findParent().findParent().findNextSibling()
for item in list(td.children):
    item = str(item).strip()
    if item.startswith('<'):
        continue
    print (item)
```

Output:

```
530.8
T1--0287
542.3
```

Comment: If this answer provides the advice or information that you needed then please mark it 'accepted'. That's the protocol here on SO. If not, please feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly, what I wanted! Have nice day :)